# Is it possible to get the time/date of a commit knowing the commit hash but without access to the repository?

Tags: git, date, git-commit

Supposing that I have the commit hash but I don't have any access to the git repository, is it possible to get the time when the commit was made?

How can this be done?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873188/1420197), the commit hashes contain dates and times when they were done.

Example:

`1484e89060b2043be0b71209bacc2254161f1a8f` was made on `Wed Sep 3 09:30:59 2014 +0300`.

Comment: what do you mean no access to git repository?  remote? local?

Comment: @DavinTryon I don't have read access to the git repository where the commit was made (if I had, I would only do a `git show foo`)

Comment: The answer you quote doesn't quite say it contains the hash -- it says it is generated from data that includes the date (and author, message, patch, etc.).

Comment: @DrewNoakes Yes, but I was thinking that the hash can be parsed somehow. For example, Mongo ObjectIDs contain dates and they can be parsed.

Comment: I have edited my answer: the project gitbrute might come close of what you are looking for, but without any guarantee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Are there any dangers in exposing git sha1 commit hashes?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41283/are-there-any-dangers-in-exposing-git-sha1-commit-hashes)":

> There is absolutely no way you can correlate the SHA 1 hash of a git commit to the actual contents of the commit.
>
> Though SHA-1 is nominally one-way, this would theoretically allow an attacker, who wants to guess the contents of an object, to verify whether his guess is correct or not.
>   **This would entail guessing exactly, down to the last bit, including time stamps and other similar things**.

So if you don't have access to the full git repo, that seems not possible.

---

As mentioned in [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1907963), the only thing you could do with a SHA1 is find a content with the same SHA1:

> The term "reverse" is not the right word to use.
>   What is meant is that **you can generate another input for which the SHA1 output matches your other SHA1 output**. This is because SHA1 has collisions.
>
> So "`foo`" could hash to 1 and "`bar`" could hash to 1 also.
>   It doesn't mean 1 means `foo`, but it means if your password is `foo`, `bar` works too when hashed and compared against a stored hash.
>
> If the original input is not very short, it's extremely unlikely that an input with the same SHA-1 hash could be found.
>   These attacks work because the passwords are weak and SHA-1 is fast to compute, not due to any weakness of SHA-1 as a cryptographic hash function.

---

Note: that (finding a content with the same SHA1) is *actually* what the project [**bradfitz/gitbrute**](https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute) does (for "fun")

> **`gitbrute`** brute-forces a pair of author+committer timestamps such that
>   the resulting git commit has your desired prefix.
>
> **It will find the most recent time that satisfies your prefix.**

I mentioned it in "[How would git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392525/6309)"

Comment: `gitbrute` seems to be a cool project. How can I use it? I already built the file (`go gitbrute.go`).

Comment: @IonicăBizău simply pass your SHA1

Comment: `./gitbrute 1484e89060b2043be0b71209bacc2254161f1a8f` doesn't output anything.

Comment: @IonicăBizău `gitbrute -h` will give you the options: `gitbrute -prefix=xxx` (see https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute/blob/master/gitbrute.go#L36-L38)

Comment: I already tried that, but I don't understand the usage. How can I generate [a commit like this](https://github.com/bradfitz/deadbeef/commit/deadbeefa1a98280231197b184c6d7ea4d2a7055) and how is gitbrute useful in finding information about commit, passing its hash?

Comment: @IonicăBizău from what I see (https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute/blob/master/gitbrute.go#L53-L58), it must be done in a repo with one commit including a file with the right content and the right author: it then compute the most recent timestamp that would satisfy the SHA1 passed in `-prefix` option.

Comment: In mathematical terms (j'étale ma science), you would say that the function "f: commit contents -> commit ID" is not *one-to-one* `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You probably think that the git commit ID is somehow encrypted data containing some information. But the Git commit IDs are hashes:

> [...] is the SHA-1 hash — a checksum of the content you’re storing plus a header [(from here)](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

Also from the cryptograpic theory we know that hashes have the [Non-invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Non-invertible) property.

So it is not possible to get any information about the commit from the ID alone.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
git log -2 --pretty=tformat:%aD:%H 1484e89060b2043be0b71209bacc2254161f1a8f
```

`%aD` gives you the authored Date.

You can add other options like

```
%cn: committer name
%an: author name

git log -2 --pretty=tformat:%aD:%cn:%an:%H 1484e89060b2043be0b71209bacc2254161f1a8f
```

If you wish to use abbreviated Hash, use `%h` instead of `%H`

You execute this via git command shell.

Comment: I don't have access to the repository. I only have the commit hash.

Comment: Ok. Without access to git repository nothing can be revealed.

Comment: What if you have access to the `.git` files ? Is it possible to work something out then ?